# Is there a way to use multiple variables inside a $_GET, $_POST or $_SESSION declaration?

Tags: php, session

Is there a way to use multiple variables inside a $_GET, $_POST or $_SESSION declaration?

For example: `$_SESSION['session_array{$i}']`.

`$i` being a counter variable so that each array I save has a different name.

I need this for saving multiple associative arrays in the $_SESSION, if there is another way this could be done this would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* (for `$_POST, $_GET, $_SESSION, $_REQUEST`, respectively) do

```
$_SESSION["session_array{$i}"]
```

But, you probably are looking for, or should rather do

```
$_SESSION['session_array'][$i]
```

Also, don't forget to use `session_start()` before trying to use session variables.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was not working for me as I was using single quotes rather than double quotes.

Comment: And yes using > $_SESSION['session_array'][$i] does seam to be the better way to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All of these support multidimensional arrays.

i.e:

```
$_SESSION['fruit']['apple']['green']; 
$_GET['country_list']['US'];
```

or with variable:

```
$_GET['count'][$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store an array in `$_SESSION` (I wouldn't recommend doing it in the other ones, though):

```
$session_array = array();
$session_array[$i] = 'some value';
$_SESSION['session_array'] = $session_array;
```

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7 looks like a good intro for you.

Comment: . . since when can't I store an array in POST?

Comment: @LeviMorrison: Okay, you *can*. It's also a **very bad idea**.

Comment: @minitech: Why is it a very bad idea?  I can't think of a reason why anyone would want to, but I also can't see why it would necessarily be *bad*...

Comment: @drrcknlsn: It makes no sense. Absolutely no sense. If I came across someone assigning *anything* to `$_GET` that wasn't included in the GET parameters I would change it.

Comment: @minitech If you mean putting things into `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_REQUEST` that wasn't already there, I agree with you.  However, things come through as arrays in `$_POST` all the time . . .

Comment: @LeviMorrison: I don't think I quite understood the question :P

Comment: @minitech: Not making sense isn't enough to make something a **very bad idea** IMO (at least not along the same lines as, say, injecting POST variables directly into database queries is a bad idea).  In other words, there aren't really any severe repercussions that I can think of.  It's just a silly thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

## Session:

For a Session, you can do:

```
$_SESSION['key']=array('one','two','three');
echo $_SESSION['key'][1] // echos 'two'
```

## POST:

For a form submit with post you can add `[]` to the end of the input name to put it in an array

```
<form method="POST" action='/' >
    <input name='arr[]' type="text" value="a">
    <input name='arr[]' type="text" value="b">
    <input name='arr[]' type="text" value="c">
</form>
```

To be accessed like:

```
echo $_POST['arr'][0] // echos 'a'
```

## GET:

Same as with the form, you just add `[]` to the variable name and it can be accessed as an array.

if you visit `www.yoursite.com/index.php?test[]=a&test[]=b`

you can do:

```
echo $_GET['test'][1] // echos 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the array multidimensional:

```
$_SESSION['session_array'][$i]
```

Regarding the `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals: You don't want to store stuff into that manually but rather by a get or post request. So that's not really an issue IMHO.

Still you can have a multidimensional `$_POST` superglobal when using input form like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="name[]">
  <input type="text" name="name[]">
</form>
```